# pyodbc DSN-less connection with AS400 / IBM midrange

Tags: pyodbc, ibm-midrange

I want to connect via pyodbc with a AS400 Database.
I configured it via the DSN syntax and it is working, but I need it DSN less.

This my current code:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
  driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
  system='192.***.***.***',
  uid='U******',
  pwd='p0*****')
```

But always I got the error:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Missing system name needed for connection. (30188) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Missing system name needed for connection. (30188)')
```

I already tried it with the older driver "IBM i Access ODBC Driver" but same error is comming up.

Did someone also had this error?

Thanks

Comment: If you are on a Windows machine you could use [dump_dsn](https://github.com/gordthompson/dump_dsn) to see what other parameters might be included in your working DSN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case - I just need to use capital letters for the functions variables:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
  DRIVER='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
  SYSTEM='192.***.***.***',
  UID='U******',
  PWD='p0*****')
```

Comment: AS/400's - forever infatuated with upper case